# "We have $x available for place Y, is it enough?"

Tags: discussion

We've had a couple of these recently:

- [$6000 for a trip to Europe ( 2 months at most) Not included flights](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18848/101)
- [Would $5000 be enough for this trip in 2014 december?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18879/101)

among others.

They'll get closed as primarily opinion based, but my concern is the more they appear, the more they show up in search results.  To make matters worse, they sometimes get answers before they get closed.

Assuming these are guaranteed to be closed eventually (unless they're REALLLLLLY specific), is there a way to prevent people from answering? Because odds are good that it gets put on hold, the question may get updated, and then the answer is horribly inaccurate.

So basically, any thoughts on either preventing these types of questions, or preventing answers to these questions before they get closed?

Comment: This is a good one. I'm looking for precedents on what should be done with low quality questions.

Answer (score 1):

Preventing these types of question is impossible - new user are allowed to ask questions and they don't really care about our rules, they just ask and only few users try to improve their questions.

But probably we can prevent these questions getting answers. A way to do this (I am aware that it's not the best one) is to downvote the answers. An answer of the primarily opinion based questions could be useful, but not the *right* answer because the question is just not answerable.

Comment: I'm almost in favour of this  I get frustrated when there's an awful question and it gets an answer, when there's really no way of accurately answering.  Especially when it has a comment asking for clarification, and close votes already. Perhaps we should start doing this, indeed...

Comment: We can also vote to delete questions if they're bad....